# PCB grounds either side of common mode choke

Tags: pcb, grounding, routing

I'm modding an old PCB that was put together long before I arrived here and I'd like some thoughts on what I think is a completely useless set-up where a separate comms ground has been routed separately to the the rest of the board's ground plane.

If you look at the first attached JPEG (please ignore the green lines, they're just unrouted traces), you can see I have labelled up the comms ground track which is separate to the large [system] ground place (It's a two layer board and I'm only showing bottom layer which is mostly system ground).

[image]

Now, top left, 24Vac or dc comes in (circled section A); at this point the two power lines are fed through a common mode choke as in the attached schematic.

[image]

You can see where I've labelled up comms ground and system ground on the schematic.

Back to the PCB, the circled area B is where the RS485 goes to the outside world; the three pins left to right are [comms] GND, A and B.

The problem I have with this is that the RS485 transceiver is connected to system ground, as schematic below. (Please accept that U4's supply pins are connected to system ground and 3V3, the latter which is, of course, referenced to system ground.)

[image]

I just do not see the use in this and the common mode choke. Surely with this set-up the common mode choke is useless? Also, isn't this comms ground pointless? Surely, by connecting the RS485 transceiver to system ground, this comms ground is essentially just connected to system ground? Or am I missing something and this system is fine as is?

Am very grateful for musings, ideas and advice.

Comment: Are you basically asking why some unspecified designer would short out one half of a common mode choke? Is that it in a nutshell?

Comment: When you put common mode choke, be sure you know what it does. Your scheme suggests you are not sure. In fact to be sure you need it, you have to understand (or for me - you have to explain) the full context of the system.

Comment: @Andy, essentially yes, *assuming*, that is what is happening here. ie Assuming I am not missing something and the described set-up is shorting out the common mode choke as I believe.

Comment: @Gregory, as I said in the post this is not my schematic. It's not even my PCB, I've just been tasked with modifying it. This is not how I would do it, but want to be sure, before I recommend modding it further, I'm not missing something. As for the full context of the system, it's one node on an RS485 bus.

Comment: Well nobody here can tell you anything different - you have the hardware and pictures in front of you; we only have pictures and your words.

Comment: @Andy, of course they can tell me different. You can see the layout and the relevant part of the circuit. I honestly don't understand why I couldn't be contradicted if I'm not seeing this clearly.

Comment: Well... Then this guy didn't know what is the choke and just put it "to separate" or something. If you think you know what to do, let's better discuss your idea.

Comment: Nobody here is going to contradict what you say - if you see it and feel it then nobody here is in a position to argue because you hold ALL the cards. I've seen worse things and they've passed EMC testing etc.. RS485 may have been added as an afterthought and that common mode choke bypassed to make comms work.

Comment: @Greg. I would connect the RS485 ground to the system ground had it been me designing it from scratch. From what I understand, the original designer put the choke in for conducted emissions reasons. Which is laudable (I think) other than the comms ground/transceiver issue.

Comment: @Andy, are you saying no-one will contradict me because my thoughts are spot-on? Or that you need more info? Sorry, not meaning to sound sarky, I am genuinely not sure what you're getting at :) BTW RS485 was never the afterthought, the choke (I am lead to believe) was. This has never been through EMC testing!

Comment: Without the hardware in my hands I cannot contradict your analysis that there is a short across one of the coils. How simple do you want me to say it?

Comment: Well, if I interpret this correctly (btw. Silkscreen on your PCB would be great to identify headers), the CM choke is meant to block CM signals from the _power supply_. For the RS485 another choke would be needed (or maybe not) within the differential signals path. As for the short, would you please point out where that would be, as Andy has suggested?

Comment: Agreed, the choke is meant to block CM signals to/from the PSU. What I am trying to get clear in my mind is whether the RS485 transceiver [actively] connects sys ground and comms ground to make the CM choke useless. I am not saying it is a matter of there being a direct short across the coil of the choke. I am also not saying I am definitely right. I am happy for someone to point out flaws in my thinking.

Comment: I think this arrangement was designed to keep the switching noise from your circuit out of your 24 volt supply rather than the other way around.  RS-485 is a balanced differential signal and is designed to be able to be decoded in the presence of common-mode noise, because the ground reference is not reliable over the long distances of the cables.  Your comms ground is avaialble for the shield on a shielded twisted pair and is not used as a reference for the 485.  Are there other circuits sharing the same power source?